# Timeout in Playwright waitForEvent('popup')

Tags: playwright

I am getting timeout errors in the following test case in Playwright:

```
1 test('should open help page', async ({ page }) => {
2   await page.locator('body').click();
3   const popupPromise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
4
5   await page.keyboard.press('Control+Shift+F1');
6   const helpPage = await popupPromise;
7
8   await expect(helpPage).toHaveURL('/help');
9 });
```

The error message:

> Error: page.waitForEvent: Page closed
> at apps\web-e2e\src\e2e\shortcut-directive.spec.ts:67:31
>
> Execution log
> waiting for event "popup"

If I run the test case, it seems that the test is really waiting for the event in line 3. But this is nothing else, what is in the [documentation for new windows](https://playwright.dev/docs/events#waiting-for-event) If I debug the test case, everything is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share a [mcve], which will need to include the page you're manipulating, or a minimal reproduction of it. It's all guesswork without that. Does running `page.locator('body').click();` trigger the popup? If so, you'll need to begin listening for the popup first, then trigger the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the script is acting too fast, before the page is fully initialized. In many cases, [Playwright's actionability auto-waiting on all actions](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability) will prevent such issues, but in this case we are not interacting with a specific control on the page. We are pressing a keyboard shortcut, and there's nothing going to stop us from doing that before the page is ready.

In this case, before doing any interactions, try to find some indicator of page readiness, and wait for that explicitly. For example there might be an element which appears last:

```
await page.getByText('logout').waitFor();
```

Or there might be an API request which is always done last:

```
const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse('https://example.com/last-api-to-load-asynchronously');
await page.goto('https://example.com/');
await responsePromise; 

// Then go ahead with your script, starting with clicking the body, etc.
```

The first kind of explicit waiting (for an element) is more preferable, since it's depending on a 'user facing' property of the app. If we wait for API requests we are depending more on the implementation of the app, which might change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Promise.all**:

```js
 await Promise.all([page.waitForEvent('popup'), page.keyboard.press('Control+Shift+F1')])
```

or wait for the event directly after kb actions:

```js
 await page.keyboard.press('Control+Shift+F1');
 await page.waitForEvent('popup');
```

Explanation why promise.all is better option is here: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5470#issuecomment-1285640689

Here's an amazing answer to Promise.all

Comment: Promise.all is no longer preferred. In most of the playwright.dev pages, it has been replaced by this pattern:

`// Start waiting for new page before clicking. Note no await.
const pagePromise = context.waitForEvent('page');
await page.getByText('open new tab').click();
const newPage = await pagePromise;
await newPage.waitForLoadState();
console.log(await newPage.title());`

(From: https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-new-pages)

It's a bit easier to understand than Promise.all.